# Dividir un string en letras C#

Tags: c#, split

estoy atorado en esta parte de mi código, quiero que mi arreglo "chars" guarde letra por letra lo que tiene mi string "cuote".

Ya había usado el split de esta forma:

```
string cuote = "De noche todos los 
gatos son pardos.";

string[] chars = cuote.Split("");

MessageBox.Show(chars[0]);
```

Por que al usar el split (" ") me separa el string en palabras lo cual está bien, pero también me gustaría tener dividido ese string en letras. Pero por alguna razón cuando uso el split ("") que debería devolver los caracteres individualmente, me devuelve el string completo.

Esto lo veo cuando por ejemplo uso un

messagebox.show(chars[0].toString())

Y devuelve el string completo cuando debería devolver solo la primera letra de la frase... en este caso "D".

Gracias de antemano si pueden ayudarme, parece que me atoré tontamente, pero la verdad es que me quedé en blanco ante esto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split regresa un arreglo de string lo divide por el caracter que se pasa como parametro, ToCharArray divide todo el string en caracteres.

```
string cuote = "De noche todos los gatos son pardos.";
char[] characters = cuote.ToCharArray();
MessageBox.Show(chars[0]); // D
MessageBox.Show(chars[3]); // n
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías añadir esto despues del split.

```
List<string>letras = new List<string>();
foreach(string palabra in chars)
{
     foreach(string letra in palabra)
     {
         letras.Add(letra);
     }
}

console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", letras);
```